# What does it mean to sign an Android app for a specific manufacturer?

Tags: android, apk, sign

I've been asked to sign an Android app for a specific manufacturer, and with my little experience in Android, I don't know what this means exactly.
The way I do the signing of the app now is by using Android Studio's "Generate Signed APK", however I haven't use any specific manufacturer details before.

Does anyone know what should be done in this case? Thank you.

Comment: You can limit your app int he play store to a single manufacturer, but you can't sign it for one.

Comment: I would interpret that as "sign the app with the platform signing key", so that you can get `signature`-level permissions. However, the only party who can ask you to do that is the manufacturer, and usually *they* would be the one to sign it -- you give them the unsigned APK to sign. I do not know who asked you to sign the app "for a specific manufacturer", so perhaps they had something else in mind.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you for your answer, I've been asked by my employer, but as an Android rookie , I didn't know what that meant.

Comment: I would ask your employer for clarification. In general, *you* can't sign an app with the platform signing key. For security reasons, the manufacturer is not going to hand over that keystore to arbitrary people. If your employer *is* the manufacturer, there should be some sort of "signing ceremony" for firmware and apps, and somebody should be in charge of that.